# In IE8 and IE9, opening links in new tabs does not work properly

Tags: internet-explorer-8, browser-tabs

When I attempt to open links in IE8 on a Windows 7 PC the tab launches but the web page does not open. This has only started happening in the last week and no obvious software changes have been made. It also happened once before and I ended up re-imaging the PC.

I have tried the following:-

- Deleted Temp Files and Cookies
- Disabled all addons
- Reset the browser
- Created a new user profile
- Internet Explorer (No Addons)
- Upgrade to IE9

I have now run out of things to try. I need to use IE8 and IE9 as they are the only browsers compatible with the help desk software that we use.

Can anybody think of anything else I should try other than re-imaging the PC again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at [How to Fix ‘Open in New Tab/Window’ problem in IE8](http://webtrickz.com/how-to-fix-open-in-new-tabwindow-problem-in-ie8/).

The method is to re-register the following DLLs:

```
regsvr32 actxprxy.dll
regsvr32 shdocvw.dll
regsvr32 mshtml.dll
regsvr32 browseui.dll
regsvr32 jscript.dll
regsvr32 vbscript.dll
regsvr32 oleaut32.dll
```

The same solution, but in registry (`.reg`) format is offered [here](http://webtrickz.com/wp-content/uploads/files/Fix_IE8Win7.reg).

Another reported fix is found in: [Repair IE8 (IE7) and IE9](http://iefaq.info/index.php?action=artikel&;cat=42&id=133&artlang=en).
The script there fixes the open in new tab or window not working, among other symptoms.

Comment: Three of those commands fail, shdocvw.dll, mshtml.dll & browseui.dll 
The error is 
[Window Title]
RegSvr32

[Content]
The module "browseui.dll" was loaded but the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found.

Make sure that "browseui.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and then try again.

[OK]

Comment: Added another possible fix. I do hope you have created a system restore point, just in case.

Comment: Will try tomorrow and tell you how it goes.